# PowerShell TCP Server

Tags: powershell, tcp, tcpserver

I would like to ask you, how it is possible to handle multiple connection threads.

I have implemented TCP server in the following way:

```
$endpoint = New-Object System.Net.IPEndPoint ([System.Net.IPAddress]::Any, 8989)
$listener = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener $endpoint
$listener.Start()

do {
    $client = $listener.AcceptTcpClient() # will block here until connection
    $stream = $client.GetStream();
    $reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader $stream
    do {
        $line = $reader.ReadLine()
        Write-Host $line -fore cyan
    } while ($line -and $line -ne ([char]4))

    $reader.Dispose()
    $stream.Dispose()
    $client.Dispose()
} while ($line -ne ([char]4))
$listener.Stop()
```

This code can handle just one thread in time.
Can you give me an advice on how to create a TCP server in PowerShell that can handle multiple clients?

Comment: Maybe spawn a [runspace](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/11/27/beginning-use-of-powershell-runspaces-part-2/) for each connected client?

Comment: would prefer [PS Jobs](https://www.howtogeek.com/138856/geek-school-learn-how-to-use-jobs-in-powershell/)

Comment: Too bad windows 10 doesn't come with netcat.exe or nc.exe (osx does).  At least it comes with curl.exe now.

Answer (score 7):

For handling multiple clients you need multiple threads and for that you need to use **[runspaces](https://blog.netnerds.net/2016/12/runspaces-simplified/)**. Below is the working code which accepts multiple clients and do the processing of each client in separate thread (runspace)

```bsh
$Global:Listener = [HashTable]::Synchronized(@{})
$Global:CnQueue = [System.Collections.Queue]::Synchronized((New-Object System.collections.queue))
$Global:space = [RunSpaceFactory]::CreateRunspace()
$space.Open()
$space.SessionStateProxy.setVariable("CnQueue", $CnQueue)
$space.SessionStateProxy.setVariable("Listener", $Listener)
$Global:newPowerShell = [PowerShell]::Create()
$newPowerShell.Runspace = $space
$Timer = New-Object Timers.Timer
$Timer.Enabled = $true
$Timer.Interval = 1000
Register-ObjectEvent -SourceIdentifier MonitorClientConnection -InputObject $Timer -EventName Elapsed -Action {
    While($CnQueue.count -ne 0) {
        $client = $CnQueue.Dequeue()
        $newRunspace = [RunSpaceFactory]::CreateRunspace()
        $newRunspace.Open()
        $newRunspace.SessionStateProxy.setVariable("client", $client)
        $newPowerShell = [PowerShell]::Create()
        $newPowerShell.Runspace = $newRunspace
        $process = {
            $stream = $client.GetStream();
            $reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader $stream
            [console]::WriteLine("Inside Processing")
            # You have client here so do whatever you want to do here.
            # This is a separate thread so if you write blocking code here, it will not impact any other part of the program
        }
        $jobHandle = $newPowerShell.AddScript($process).BeginInvoke()
        #jobHandle you need to save for future to cleanup
    }
}
$listener = {
    $Listener['listener'] = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener("127.0.0.1", "1234")
    $Listener['listener'].Start()
    [console]::WriteLine("Listening on :1234")
    while ($true) {
        $c = $Listener['listener'].AcceptTcpClient()
        If($c -ne $Null) {
            [console]::WriteLine("{0} >> Accepted Client " -f (Get - Date).ToString())
            $CnQueue.Enqueue($c)
        }
        Else {
            [console]::WriteLine("Shutting down")
            Break
        }
    }
}
$Timer.Start()
$Global:handle = $newPowerShell.AddScript($listener).BeginInvoke()
```

For more detailed example please go [here](https://github.com/proxb/PoshChat/blob/master/Start-PoshChatServer.ps1)